# No multi boot after installing Ubuntu 12 with WinXP

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot

I managed to install Ubuntu 12 alongside with my previously installed WinXP on my Toshiba Satellite C655. When the installation finished, I restarted the laptop and prepared myself to select Ubuntu from the multi boot menu. I was surprised when it booted to WinXP WITHOUT asking me which OS to load... No multi boot menu at all... I'm new to Linux, hope someone can help me to fix this. Please let me know if you need some technical details from me.
Thank you in advance.
Regards, Viktor

Answer (score 2):

You should reinstall grub with [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on ubuntu live mode .

Answer (score 0):

Do try to use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix the system. It will (re)install Grub and hopefully get it to recognize your Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had all kinds of problems with a 12.04 install alongside XP, in logical or primary partitions, either automatically or manually created - it didn't matter. Couldn't get grub multi-boot to come up and the computer would go directly into Windows no matter what I did. Boot-repair asked me to cut and paste 3 command lines that couldn't be executed because there was nothing to be found in the target location (that is to say that grub wasn't "there" to be uninstalled). I did everything from a FIXMBR prior to reinstalling 12.04, to a complete reformat and reinstall of XP, to a complete reformat of the entire disk and just a lone install of 12.04 to simply eliminate the possibility that I had a bad install disk (test which showed everything was fine . . . other than the fact that the install changed my BIOS boot settings to "Ubuntu", but I suppose that is normal . . .).

On the other hand, testing showed that Ubuntu 10.10 correctly installed grub without issue after previously installing XP and manually configuring primary partitions, in contrast to the 12.04 failure to get the job done, and boot-repair's incapability of fixing the glitch.

As a windoz user accustomed to workarounds and not heavy on programming, and just about out of options, I decided to do a clean install of XP again, (formatting the entire disk and starting from scratch), and THEN to install Ubuntu 10.10, and THEN to *upgrade* to 12.04 using the 12.04 install program, and **everything went off without a hitch**.